# How to parse json which is parsed from xml conversion inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, underscore.js

I am trying to parse in this result of data which i obtained from xml conversion to json parsing :

```
var output = [{"SearchResults:searchresults":{"$":{"xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","xsi:schemaLocation":"someurl","xmlns:SearchResults":"someurl"},"request":[{"keyval":["keydata"]",...}]}]}]}]}]}]}}]
```

How to get keydata of keyval. I tried parsing and stringify also but no results.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure how this relates to JSON... Does your data contain `var output...`?

Comment: No i have assigned that json object to output. For explaination, i have stringified the output from the console and i have pasted. Its dynamic result.

Comment: you should post detail code to understand exact issue and agree with @Álvaro G. Vicario

Comment: This is what i am getting the output after xml webservice conversion to json :
 
    [{"SearchResults:searchresults":{"$":{"xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","xsi:schemaLocation":"http://www.someurl.com/static.xsd http://www.someurlstatic.com/vstatic/LATEST/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd","xmlns:SearchResults":"http://www.someurl.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd"},"request":[{"address":["2114 Bigelow Ave"],"city":["Seattle"]}],"message":[{"text":["Request successfully processed"],"code":["0"]}]}]}]}]}]

How can i fetch the  city name from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unreadable comment does not really shed much light on the issue. My guess is that you retrieve JSON though AJAX with jQuery, thus your JSON is already decoded when you display it in the console (that's what jQuery is good at) and you no longer have a JSON string but good old JavaScript array. Your question is probably the classical "how do I read a deeply nested piece of data" we see a lot here.

Using proper indentation everything's cleaner:

```
var output = [
    {
        "SearchResults:searchresults": {
            "$": {
                "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                "xsi:schemaLocation": "someurl",
                "xmlns:SearchResults": "someurl"
            },
            "request": [
                {
                    "keyval": [
                        "keydata"
                    ]",
...
```

1. First item of array:

   ```
   output[0]
   ```
2. First key:

   ```
   output[0]["SearchResults:searchresults"]
   ```
3. Next level:

   ```
   output[0]["SearchResults:searchresults"]["$"]
   ```

... etc.